# Did Christopher Nolan intend to imply a conspiracy?

Tags: oppenheimer

In the closing moments of *Oppenheimer*, Lewis Strauss is told that a notable dissenter to his appointment is a young Senator John F Kennedy.

As this happens in the closing moments of the film, and is one of the last lines delivered, is Nolan implying that Strauss might have exacted his revenge on JFK for this snub?  That is, Is Nolan implying that this dissension is the genesis of JFK being killed, and that Lewis Strauss was a significant principal behind his assassination?

Comment: To whomever VTC, what is unclear?

Comment: Actual history would suggest Kennedy’s role in Strauss not being confirmed was relatively minor. For example, senator Clinton Anderson was more strongly and publicly opposed to Strauss’ confirmation than anyone else, according to at least two sources. More likely that Nolan wants to cement Strauss as a real life “bad guy” in the eyes of the audience, since Kennedy is still pretty popular.

Comment: I'm totally confused as why there's a close vote on this question

Comment: @ToddWilcox Also could be using the widely-recognized Kennedy to help cement the time period for the audience. To the majority of people, names like Strauss', the other senators, even most of the scientists are not well known and might come across as just 'generic' government figures. Mentioning JFK specifically helps to relate the events to things people are more familiar with.

Comment: Imaginative speculations like yours is how conspiracy theories start, and why there are a 1,000 different JFK conspiracy theories. Actually now 1,001.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kennedy was just one of [47 Democratic Senators](https://library.cqpress.com/cqalmanac/document.php?id=cqal59-1334314) who voted against Strauss's confirmation, and the vote was largely along party lines:

> The Senate's rejection of Lewis L. Strauss as Secretary of Commerce June 19 came after months of acrimonious debate, hearings and public charges and countercharges. Long-standing feuds over issues, differing philosophies of government and sharp personality conflicts all were elements in this protracted controversy, but the final vote adhered closely to party lines. On the June 19 roll-call vote two Republicans – Sens. William Langer (N.D.) and Margaret Chase Smith (Maine) – and 47 Democrats voted against the nomination; 31 Republicans and 15 Democrats – all but four of them from the South – voted for the confirmation.
>
> ..
>
> The four leading Democratic Presidential possibilities – Sens. Lyndon B. Johnson (Texas), Hubert H. Humphrey (Minn.), John F. Kennedy (Mass.) and Stuart Symington (Mo.) – all opposed the Strauss nomination.

I have yet to come across any interview with Nolan in which he claims to have intended to imply such a conspiracy. While I don't have a statement by Nolan on why exactly Kennedy was singled out as opposing the confirmation (other well-known Democrats such as future President Lyndon B. Johnson and future Vice President Humbert Humphrey did so as well), it is reasonable to assume that it was because Nolan assumes the audience knows that the President who succeeded Dwight D. Eisenhower, who appointed Strauss, was Kennedy.

Comment: https://library.cqpress.com/ is paywalled.

Comment: Added pertinent quotes from paywalled page.  Feel free to edit further or roll back as you see fit.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's a real stretch to think that Nolan is pointing at Strauss as a possible instigator of a plot to kill Kennedy. This is "Oppenheimer", not "Game of Thrones". Assassination is pretty rare in US politics, bitter political fights are not. The common tools in political fights are artful use of bureaucratic regulations, carefully placed leaks, and artfully timed bald faced lies. Strauss's arc in "Oppenheimer" demonstrates that he was a master of all of these. Strauss wasn't involved black-bag operations or wet work. His tool was to hand Oppenheimer's security file over to folks who, technically, weren't supposed to see it.

I think what Nolan is getting at by bringing up Kennedy is the ebb and flow of political power. In 1944 Oppenheimer was the "essential man". In 1945 he was the heroic father of the weapon that won the war. In 1954 the US is at the peak of the red scare and Oppenheimer's enemies are easily able to kick him to the curb. In 1959 Strauss thinks he's at the apex of his career, but the political winds are changing, Joe McCarthy is dead and in disrepute and and Strauss underestimates the political pull of Oppenheimer's friends looking (as they see it) for justice. Kennedy helps torpedo Strauss's nomination to the cabinet. In 1963 Kennedy is working towards awarding Oppenheimer the Fermi medal and putting his public seal of approval on Oppenheimer's rehabilitation.

Comment: This sees to be your own personal opinion. Can you offer any evidence that this is what *the director* was thinking?